# BHO HtmlEventObject crashes

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I have a browser helper object written in C++ but I have a problem when recieving a OnHelp HtmlEvent.

When I try to access a attribute the browser crashes.

```
VARIANT_BOOL STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnHelp(IHTMLEventObj2 *pEvtObj)
{
    std::cout << "OnHelp Event" << std::endl;

    if(pEvtObj != NULL) {
        VARIANT var;
        pEvtObj->getAttribute(L"formID", 0, &var);
        std::cout << (char*)var.bstrVal << std::endl;
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "PELEM = NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    return VARIANT_TRUE;
}
```

It crashes on the getAttribute line for some reason? When doing this in C# it works perfectly. I hope somebody can help me fix this.

Edit:

The real problem was with the parameter I needed to use IHTMLEventObj and then query for IHTMLEventObj2.

```
VARIANT_BOOL STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnHelp(IHTMLEventObj *pEvtObj)
{
    IHTMLEventObj2 *pEvtObj2;
    pEvtObj->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLEventObj2, (void**)&pEvtObj2);

    if(pEvtObj2 != NULL) {
        VARIANT var;
        pEvtObj2->getAttribute(CComBSTR(L"url"), 0, &var);
        std::cout << _bstr_t(var.bstrVal) << std::endl;
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "PELEM = NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    return VARIANT_TRUE;
}
```

Comment: And read this before you do anymore COM programming: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first arg for getAttribute is a `BSTR`, but your passing a `wchar_t*`/`unsigned int *` depending on VC compile settings.
`BSTR` is a system string which is expected to be deallocated by the receiving method.

Try

```
#define DOM_ANON_STRING(x)          (_bstr_t(x))
pEvtObj->getAttribute(DOM_ANON_STRING(L"formID"), 0, &var);
```

Comment: _bstr_t is evil.  Just use a BSTR or CComBSTR.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Perhaps you could explain more on your thoughts of evil.  I think we don't use CComBSTR as some previous dev avoided CComBSTR due to links to MFC for instance, and the original problem is failure to allocate memory properly for the BSTR which is what the class is helping with, so saying use BSTR doesn't help.